# Calling OneHotEncoding results into Java Heap Space Error

Tags: python, java, xgboost, h2o

When running `xGboost` Package in `H2o` throws Java heap space error. But when the memory is cleared manually it works fine.

I often use
del df
del something
import gc
gc.collect()

in order to clear memory. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
import h2o
from h2o.tree import H2OTree
from h2o.estimators import H2OIsolationForestEstimator, H2OXGBoostEstimator,

encoding = "one_hot_explicit"

baseModel = H2OXGBoostEstimator(model_id = modelId, ntrees = 100, 
                                    max_depth = 3,seed = 0xDECAF,
                                    sample_rate = 1,
                                    categorical_encoding = encoding,
                                    keep_cross_validation_predictions=True, 
                                    nfolds = 10
                                    )
    ## TRAIN DATA
    baseModel.train(x = predictor_columns, y = "label", training_frame = train.rbind(valid))
```

Error Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/docs/code/000_pyGraph/dec_rf_gb_xgb.py", line 151, in <module>
        decxgb.xgb_cvs(df=df, year=year, model_path=model_path, 
      File "/docs/code/000_pyGraph/dec_xgb.py", line 90, in xgb_cvs
        baseModel.train(x = predictor_columns, y = "label", training_frame = train.rbind(valid))
      File "/home/miniconda3/envs/tf-gpu-mem-day/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h2o/estimators/estimator_base.py", line 123, in train
        self._train(parms, verbose=verbose)
      File "/home/miniconda3/envs/tf-gpu-mem-day/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h2o/estimators/estimator_base.py", line 215, in _train
        job.poll(poll_updates=self._print_model_scoring_history if verbose else None)
      File "/home/miniconda3/envs/tf-gpu-mem-day/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h2o/job.py", line 90, in poll
        raise EnvironmentError("Job with key {} failed with an exception: {}\nstacktrace: "
    OSError: Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_8508e7043b6647f7868aa83a3f6842d4 failed with an exception: DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: 'Java heap space', caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    stacktrace: 
    DistributedException from /127.0.0.1:54321: 'Java heap space', caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:660)
        at water.MRTask.getResult(MRTask.java:670)
        at water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:530)
        at water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:412)
        at water.MRTask.doAll(MRTask.java:397)
        at water.fvec.Vec.doCopy(Vec.java:514)
        at water.fvec.Vec.makeCopy(Vec.java:500)
        at water.fvec.Vec.makeCopy(Vec.java:493)
        at water.fvec.Vec.makeCopy(Vec.java:487)
        at water.util.FrameUtils$CategoricalOneHotEncoder$CategoricalOneHotEncoderDriver.compute2(FrameUtils.java:768)
        at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1677)
        at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:976)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479)
        at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 0):

XGBoost in H2O actually runs outside the H2O Cluster (Java heap), so when you start up H2O with `h2o.init()` you need to make sure to save enough RAM to run both H2O and XGBoost.  I think that might be the issue you're having, but please let me know if this does not fix it.

We recommend leaving at least 1/3 of the RAM for XGBoost.  So if you have 30GB RAM, give 20GB for H2O (`h2o.init(max_mem_size="30G"`), which leaves 10GB for XGBoost.